# Googlesheets CSV auto-update polylines to ArcGIS Online Maps?

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, polyline-creation, google-sheets

I have been able to establish a ArcGIS Online map that auto-updates from a CSV spreadsheet within Google Sheets. The data that is auto-updating is point data with associated tabular data that will change over time, the spatial data will likely remain the same.

The issue lies in establishing polyline data in a CSV Google sheets file. I associated tabular data with points to test out the process, which has been shown to work. Now I need to have each row in the CSV to have the spatial information to form a polyline, as opposed to the lat and lon, which is required to draw a point in ArcGIS Online.

Is there some sort of ArcGIS Desktop tool that can take all the vertexes within a polyline, and establish those as functional lat and lon within a row of a CSV or shapefile field for drawing that polyline within ArcGIS Online. I have seen various coding solutions on the web, which I am not sure would actually address the goal I am trying to achieve.